# How do I loop this JSON string to get result by certain key?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I have a JSON string.

```
var j_string = '[{"ID":"A001","TYPE":"1"},{"ID":"A002","TYPE":"1"},{"ID":"B001","TYPE":"2"},{"ID":"B002","TYPE":"2"},{"ID":"B003","TYPE":"2"}]';
```

How do I loop this string based on `TYPE` to get the value of `ID` ?

My current script:

```
//var txt_memo_int = "";
$.each($.parseJSON(j_string), function(){

     $.each(this, function(key,value){

        if(key == "TYPE"){
            if(value == "2"){
               alert(value);
            }
        }

    });
});
```

My desired output  :

```
ID
B001
B002
B003
```

Comment: The j_string is in a format of a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite easy, just use `filter` to remove the items you don't want and then print it the way you want :)

```js
const j_string = '[{"ID":"A001","TYPE":"1"},{"ID":"A002","TYPE":"1"},{"ID":"B001","TYPE":"2"},{"ID":"B002","TYPE":"2"},{"ID":"B003","TYPE":"2"}]';
const requiredType = '2';
const filteredResult = JSON.parse(j_string).filter(({TYPE}) => TYPE === requiredType);

filteredResult.forEach(({ID}) => console.log(ID));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate the array of objects and check the property `TYPE` for the wanted value and output `ID`.

```js
var array = [{"ID":"A001","TYPE":"1"},{"ID":"A002","TYPE":"1"},{"ID":"B001","TYPE":"2"},{"ID":"B002","TYPE":"2"},{"ID":"B003","TYPE":"2"}]

array.forEach(o => {
    if (o.TYPE === '2') {
        console.log(o.ID);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
     var j_string = '[{"ID":"A001","TYPE":"1"},{"ID":"A002","TYPE":"1"},{"ID":"B001","TYPE":"2"},{"ID":"B002","TYPE":"2"},{"ID":"B003","TYPE":"2"}]';

function myFunction() {
    var parseJString = JSON.parse(j_string);
    var storeArr = [];
    parseJString.find(function(obj){
        if(obj.TYPE == 2){
            storeArr.push(obj.ID);
        }
    });
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = storeArr;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an array of objects like Teemu said. It can be done in javascript like this:

```
var j_string = [
    {"ID":"A001","TYPE":"1"},
    {"ID":"A002","TYPE":"1"},
    {"ID":"B001","TYPE":"2"},
    {"ID":"B002","TYPE":"2"},
    {"ID":"B003","TYPE":"2"} ]

for(i=0; i<j_string.length; i++) {
    if(j_string[i].TYPE === '2') {
        console.log(j_string[i].ID)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pivot the JSON array against TYPE and cache it, if this is an operation you would perform often.
The simplest way to do the same would be

```
var j_string = [{"ID":"A001","TYPE":"1"},{"ID":"A002","TYPE":"1"},{"ID":"B001","TYPE":"2"},{"ID":"B002","TYPE":"2"},{"ID":"B003","TYPE":"2"}]
var typeMap = j_string.reduce((acc,item) => {
    if(!acc[item['TYPE']]) {
        acc[item['TYPE']] = [];
    }
    acc[item['TYPE']].push(item);
    return acc;
},{})
```

Now, you have a new object of the form

```
{
  1: [{"ID":"A001","TYPE":"1"},{"ID":"A002","TYPE":"1"},
  2: [{"ID":"B001","TYPE":"2"},{"ID":"B002","TYPE":"2"},{"ID":"B003","TYPE":"2"}]
}
```

Clearly, getting your value against type would now be trivial. just take `typeMap[type]` where type stores the type you want.